# How to obtain DBL_MIN without #include <limits> in C++

Tags: c++, double

I'm writing a header/cpp file pair and want to minimize the things I need to include in the cpp file. I use `#include <limits>` to access `DBL_MAX`, and wanted to know if there's another way to get that value and stick it in a variable. By the way, it looks like bit manipulation is not allowed/supported in C++.

It is also crucial that the value is exactly the maximum value down to the last bit, not "close" to it.

Comment: Just include the correct header file (`cfloat` not `limits`) and get on with life.  It's not going to hurt anything.

Comment: Why are you trying to "minimize the things [you] need to include"?

Comment: Bit manipulation is allowed/supported in C++, just as it is in C - only on integral types, not floating point types.

Comment: In any event, trying to minimise inclusion of standard headers from a source file is pointless in practice, since most workarounds typically involve hacks with implementation-defined, unspecified, or undefined behaviour (i.e. assuming something that is specific to a particular compiler, floating point representation, or something).   Since you haven't specified any reason to avoid inclusion (other than a "want") I'm voting for closure.

Comment: It's important to keep the *header* fast (i.e. free from unnecessary includes), as it's read by every translation unit that includes your library.  The source file is read just once, and irrelevant headers there are much less important to deal with.  (The perfectionist I am, I still tidy them up, but the impact is much, much smaller).

Comment: @Peter You can manipulate bits of anything in C and C++, including floating points. Actually, in the old days, FPUs were not common and the functionality would make use of an interrupt that would translate the instruction in a function call and the manipulation would happen "in software", manipulating the floating point bits (possibly in assembly, though, but they could have had C implementations too). It's, of course, a lot of work. Today, I still like to access the sign and/or the exponent with bit manipulation. For example, in my tests I like to compute an epsilon to compare numbers.

Comment: I believe the includes without a .h are allowed by the specification not to read a file at all but simply cause symbols to be defined as per the spec for the file in question.  And if the compiler is nonetheless going out to the header, standard headers are the kind of thing typically installed in the computer's main physical drive instead of on a file server, and that means the OS may be caching the header in memory.  Either way, this include directive not be causing the computer to read an extra file at all.  (And even if it did, it's probably only milliseconds.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only correct way is

```
#include <cfloat>
```

If you are willing to limit your code to run only on platforms that use a particular floating-point representation (e.g. IEEE-754, if Annex F "IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic" is provided), you might be able to type-pun a byte array containing a fixed value (e.g. using the [examples on Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)).  But that's a big portability price to pay for something your compiler writer has done for you.  Compare that against the gain you might achieve each time you build your library (hint: you'll struggle to measure the difference), and you'll find that hacking your own version of the standard constant is really not worth it.

Even if you were including `<cfloat>` from the *header* for your library (which - you hope - will be done many, many more times than building the implementation), making it non-portable to save a handful of microseconds is unlikely to be a good trade-off.

Answer (score -2):

Just assign these values to a variable: DBL_MIN is 2.2250738585072014e-308; DBL_MAX is 1.7976931348623157e308 .

Comment: The whole point of using the definitions from the standard library is that it gives you a way to get *the exact value for your platform*.  This answer is just wrong.

Comment: @TobySpeight So DBL_MAX and DBL_MIN may not resolve to double-precision values on some platforms?

Comment: Double precision values are not necessarily the same size on all platforms.  C specifies minimum requirements, not absolutes, so type `double` may be a 64-bit, 80-bit or 128-bit representation and be conformant.  These will all have differing values for `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX`.  Not all the world is IEEE-754!  (and C is not Java)

Comment: @TobySpeight Point taken on using the header but the OP asked for a way to get the values *without* the header. Assuming OP's platform uses doubles (highly likely -- can be verified nonetheless), my answer seems fine. (Do you have an example platform that does not use double-precision for those constants? How about a link to the C doc that specifies this? Thanks.)

Comment: Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950619/type-of-dbl-max (supports assertion that DBL_MAX does not have to be a double, but in practice it seems always to be).