# Type of DBL_MAX

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer

I saw this code somewhere

```
printf("DBL_MAX     :   %g\n", (double) DBL_MAX);
```

Is the cast necessary? I cannot find anything in the standard which specifies `DBL_MAX` must actually have (or promote to) type `double`.

Answer (score 4):

`DBL_MAX` is specified to be a macro, so in itself, does not have a type.

The requirement from the 1999 C standard is that `DBL_MAX` must expand to a constant value that is at least `1E+37`, but nothing is said about its actual type.    Since it represents the implementation-defined maximum value that a `double` can represent, logic would suggest the expansion is a value that can be converted to a `double` without any change (e.g. loss of precision).

This logic would allow but not require `DBL_MAX` to be of type `double`.   It could also be of type `long double` (since it is also required that a `long double` can exactly represent all values that a `double` can).

Practically, it is difficult to envisage an implementation which has `DBL_MAX` expand to a constant that is not of type `double`, and I certainly have never heard mention of one.   But that does not mean it is required.  `printf("DBL_MAX     :   %g\n", (double) DBL_MAX)` provides a conservative (in the sense of making provision for a possibility that is allowed, even if it might not occur) guarantee that a value of type `double` is passed to `printf()`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's anything in the standard that really says that `DBL_MAX` is an expression of type `double`.

The description in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.4.2.2p12, which specifies `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX`, and `LDBL_MAX`, is:

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by constant
>   expressions with implementation-defined values that are greater than
>   or equal to those shown:

(all three must be at least `1E+37`).

Just as a matter of common sense, I can think of no good reason for the expression to which the `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX`, and `LDBL_MAX` macros expand *not* to be of types `float`, `double`, and `long double`, respectively. I suspect that the authors of the standard simply assumed that they would be of the expected type. I personally would be comfortable omitting the cast and using `DBL_MAX` rather than `(double)DBL_MAX`.

If an implementation used:

```
#define DBL_MAX 1.79769313486231570815e+308L
```

giving it a type of `long double`, it would be counterintuitive, but I don't see any requirement in the Standard that it would violate.